# Docker error - "cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied"

Tags: ubuntu, debian, docker, nfs, ubuntu-20.04

I'm currently learning Docker and just migrated to an Ubuntu 20.04.2 VM running in VMware workstation player as my Raspberry Pi 2 running Debian 9 has kicked the bucket.  Seems Docker requires some special permissions in Ubuntu and I'm baffled as to what those are.  The primary error message when running any docker command is:

```
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

My home directory is NFS mounted, but UID/GID mappings between the VM and NAS are in sync, and I can create and modify files & directories in my home directory without issue. If I change the cwd to say /tmp, the error message is a little more descriptive:

```
j5@ubuntu20:/tmp$ docker build ~/Dockerfile
cannot create user data directory: /mnt/homes/j5/snap/docker/796: Permission denied
```

But the funny thing is the directory ***was*** created and has normal permissions:

```
j5@ubuntu20:/tmp$ ls -la /mnt/homes/j5/snap/docker/796
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 j5 users  0 Jul  8 01:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 j5 users 32 Jul  8 01:26 ..
```

I know Terraform has trouble creating lock files on NFS-mounted directories and am suspecting docker has a similar requirement?

Comment: You must also check permissions of all containing directories.